# Запись данные JSON в class

Tags: json, xcode, swift4

Получаю вот такой JSON с сервера:

```
[{"deleted":false,"updatedAt":"2017-12-25T15:04:40.416Z","createdAt":"2017-12-14T12:15:33Z","version":"AAAAAAAAB/U=","id":"3311b847c5fa4878a1afef722fa8b7a0","userId":"95777a45afc241dd87f3cae3274fe0af","days":0,"name":"курс 2"},{"deleted":false,"updatedAt":"2017-12-29T05:27:49.692Z","createdAt":"2017-12-29T05:27:49.692Z","version":"AAAAAAAACHI=","id":"744420c6d8ac4ff1800087bd7464e7b8","userId":"175d3f1625fd4c87bd57bafabaac7942","days":10,"name":"два"},{"deleted":false,"updatedAt":"2017-12-28T23:38:40.987Z","createdAt":"2017-12-28T23:38:40.987Z","version":"AAAAAAAACGk=","id":"81adaabf04944fa48c7df32c8e1c0659","userId":"95777a45afc241dd87f3cae3274fe0af","days":12,"name":"kurs 4"},{"deleted":false,"updatedAt":"2018-01-09T14:31:09.409Z","createdAt":"2018-01-09T14:31:09.409Z","version":"AAAAAAAADus=","id":"8a95ee90414642e199da22692801d360","userId":"175d3f1625fd4c87bd57bafabaac7942","days":10,"name":"Английский basic level"},{"deleted":false,"updatedAt":"2018-01-01T16:03:37.017Z","createdAt":"2018-01-01T16:03:36.954Z","version":"AAAAAAAADBw=","id":"b04070c377c24b7295fda8ec8484dca5","userId":"95777a45afc241dd87f3cae3274fe0af","days":7,"name":"Курс 1"},{"deleted":false,"updatedAt":"2017-12-25T15:01:07.619Z","createdAt":"2017-12-12T22:33:33Z","version":"AAAAAAAAB+4=","id":"c2ea7d5796384b6f88cdf3299f3470d6","userId":"175d3f1625fd4c87bd57bafabaac7942","days":60,"name":"Biology"}]
```

Как эти данные можно записать в отдельный class?

Вот код:

```
class CourseTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var courses = [Courses]()
var idUser = ["Download..."]
var arr = ["Download..."];

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
    let url = URL(string: "http://teachmeserv.azurewebsites.net/tables/course/")

    let task = session.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
        let texto = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        print(texto!)
        self.arr = self.retornaAtores(data: data!)
        self.idUser = self.retornaAtores2(data: data!)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    })
    task.resume()

}
func retornaAtores(data: Data) -> [String]{
    var ret = [String]()
    let ret2 = [String]()
    do{
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! Array<Any>
        if let results = json as? Array<Dictionary<String, Any>> {
            for result in results {
                guard let name = result["name"] as? String else { print("1"); return ret}
                 guard let id = result["id"] as? String else { print("1"); return ret2}

                Courses(name: name, id: id)
                ret.append(name)
               // print(json)
                print(courses)
            }
        }
    }catch let error as NSError{
        print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    return ret
}

func retornaAtores2(data: Data) -> [String]{
    var ret2 = [String]()
    do{
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! Array<Any>

        if let results = json as? Array<Dictionary<String, Any>> {
            for result in results {
                guard let id = result["id"] as? String else { print("1"); return ret2}
                ret2.append(id)

            }
        }
    }catch let error as NSError{
        print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    return ret2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для начала создадим описание данных. Вы можете использовать класс либо структуру, как в моем примере:

```
struct ParsedObject: Decodable {
    var deleted: Bool
    var updatedAt: Date
    var createdAt: Date
    var version: String
    var id: String
    var userId: String
    var days: Int
    var name: String
}
```

Мы отметили структуру как `Decodable`, чтобы использовать встроеннную возможность Swift4 для кодирования `JSON`.

В Вашем примере используется разный формат даты (в некоторых случаях присутствуют миллисекунды, а в некоторых нет), поэтому нам понадобятся два форматтера дат. Первый будет парсить дату с миллисекундами:

```
let dataWithMillisecondsFormatter = DateFormatter()
dataWithMillisecondsFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSS'Z'"
dataWithMillisecondsFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")!
```

Второй будет парсить дату без миллисекунд:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")!
```

Создадим `JSONDecoder`.

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
```

и зададим ему кастомный парсер даты с использование созданных выше парсеров.

```
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .custom { decoder in
    let formattedDate = try decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(String.self)
    if let date = dataWithMillisecondsFormatter.date(from: formattedDate) {
        return date
    } else if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: formattedDate) {
        return date
    } else {
        throw NSError(domain: "Date decoding", code: 0, userInfo: nil)
    }
}
```

С парсингом всех остальных полей проблем не возникнет, так как они стандартные для платформы.

Запустим парсинг массива с объектами из данных:

```
let array = try? decoder.decode([ParsedObject].self, from: data)
```

Все данные записаны в массив `array` в виде объектов `ParsedObject`.
Этот пример можно улучшить, добавив обработку ошибки в случае некорректных данных, на данный момент в этом случае array будет равен `nil`.